# .htaccess / php redirect 301 302 exclusivly for web crawlers

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, google-crawlers

Is there a to redirect only traffic that comes from webcrawlers (mainly google) while maintaining the "normal" user traffic intact ?

My scenario is as follows :

A client had a website on a domain ( www.domain-1.com ) which he sold (the domain).
The website is now being moved to a second domain (www.domain-2.com ) .

Is there a way to tell crawlers that the SAME website was moved from domain-1 to domain-2 while not forgetting that domain-1 now has different content of it's own ?
(and thus somehow maintaining the old domain-2 indexed links and rankings ?)

Usually, I know in PHP i do a normal permanent redirect sending headers like :

```
   header('Location: http://www.example.com/', true, 301);
    exit;
```

But in the above case , I am not sure if I should use :

- A . 302 / 302 / some other unknown to me
- B .php / .htaccess

Is that even possible ?

Please any advice would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Do you own both websites? If not you have a problem.

Comment: @SalmanA no, I do not own both, but the new owner of domain-1 (the old domain) has granted me access for redirection for a month as part of the sale terms ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it considered to be a bad practice to show different content to crawlers than users. Also letting google index the same content in two different domain could hurt the pagerank.

If you are sure that its a good idea to keep the same content in separate domains, try using the [cross-domain rel="canonical" link element](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.hu/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain.html) to mark the content that got moved from `domain-1` to `domain-2`, leaving the new content unmarked. Google's crawlers should understand these.

---

#### Distilling comment discussion:

1. If you moving your site (removing the content from the old site eventually) - act according to the [Moving your site](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83105) guide and use 301 redirects as long as you can from the old place to the new. (you can try [adjusting the crawl rate](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48620) to make the links update faster)
2. If your situation would end up creating duplicate content (the old site keep the content as well) either in-site or on multiple domains, use [canonical rels](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.hu/2009/10/reunifying-duplicate-content-on-your.html).
3. Avoid threating search bots differently than users (referred as "cloaking" in [google's webmaster docs](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66355)), it hurts expectations and possibly pageranks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you (or I ) might have misunderstood. I will NOT have the same content on both domains. I the original domain will have it's own separate content now ..

Comment: Yeah, i've got the feeling that i'm not clear enought (so expanded a the link sentence a little). My understanding is that if you only mark the urls that *are* moved with this, and leave new stuff without these then it should do what you want.

Comment: Problem is , I can not mark any single elements . the website itself will NO LONGER be on the domain-1. it will move entirely to domain-2 and the owner of domain-1 will put some other content . in the meanwhile we got his permission to make some (global ) temporary redirection for a month or so. But since this scenario is a bit unique, I have no idea how to handle it . this is why i thought of doing a redirect only for the crawlers, while normal users will see the new owner's "under construction" page ..

Comment: I think if you already have the content up in the new domain, just redirect everyone there while you can as described in [Moving your site](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83105) (and i think my original answer just became is completely irrelevant)

Comment: thanks, your canonical tip was very helpful, i might do something in that direction ..